# Facebook Messenger Bot 'sender action typing on' in node.js

Tags: facebook, bots, messenger

How do I make my chatbot to indicate that it is typing? 
The following code doesn't work at all...

```
function sendQuickReply(recipientId){
    var messageData = {
      recipient: {
        id: recipientId
      },
      sender_action: "typing_on",
      message:{
        text:"$%",
        quick_replies:[
          {
            content_type:"text",
            title:"%^",
            payload:"morning", 
            image_url:"http://emojip
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't send a message with a text/image/payload and a sender action.
You need to write 2 functions (or requests). And the request with the sender action needs to have only the recipient id and the sender action in parameters.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/sender-actions